# Jquery UI Datepicker with custom trigger weird issue FF only

Tags: jquery, user-interface, triggers, uidatepicker

Check out http://www.ukase.ca/new.php­

My Calendar trigger displays fine, but only the 20px right portion of the image is clickable...

IE8 is fine

Comment: Your page 404 Not Found for me. Maybe you better create separate example on jsFiddle?